пишу бота на aiogram3 и он не хочет отправлять приветственное сообщение в чат
import types
from aiogram.types import ContentType, Message
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, F, Router

bot = Bot

router = Router()


@router.message_handler(content_types=[ContentType.NEW_CHAT_MEMBERS])
async def new_members_handler(message: Message):
    new_member = message.new_chat_members[0]
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Добро пожаловать, {new_member.mention}")


message_handler(content_types=...) Вы точно на aiogram пишете?

Да, я просто начинающий и этот код я нашёл в интернете на гид хабе, и не могу понять почему не работает
